# How to deploy Amazon S3 profile credentials in different server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 for uploading files and downloading files from bucket.

Amazon S3 references credentials from Profiles which is working fine on my local server. I am not sure how to deploy on development, staging and on Live server?

SDK stores profile in encrypted in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit folder`.

How that will work on my development, staging and on Live server?

Answer (score 0):

Are those servers running on EC2? If so, then you should consider using IAM Roles.

If you create a role, attach the appropriate access policy to it, and then associate that role with an EC2 instance (at launch time), then the SDK is able to obtain the credentials by itself in a very secure manner. No need to deploy and store credentials on your instances.

Also, be sure to sign up for AWS Support, which is probably a more appropriate place for urgent matters: http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport